# How to remove html effect from a string using php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display short description without any **markup** in read-more section. I want to display small portion of content.

Content Looks like:

> **This is my car.** *This may be a* <strike>funny</strike> *content*. This is a demo text. This is a demo text.
>
> This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is
>   a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text.

Readmore Looks Like:

> This is my car. This may be a funny content.

My question is how to remove the effect of html and display a normal string.

Comment: If you want to preserve the actual content, but remove the HTML tags, you can use `strip_tags()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php - this preserves the original text (just removes the formatting) though.

Comment: You just apply `strip_tags()` to the "read more" portion of it, not the entire string. Although if you want to remove the style of the HTML attributes, put it all into a div which you style in a way that it becomes normal text inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Following your example, your input string will look like this:

```
<b>This is my car.</b> <em>This may be a <strike>funny</strike> content.</em>
<p>This is a demo text. This is a demo text.</p>
```

let's consider this is going to be inside a variable $mystring

> ```
> echo $mystring;
> ```
>
> **This is my car.** *This may be a <strike>funny</strike> content.*

with **strip_tags** function and only $mystring as parameter you remove all the tags:

> ```
> echo strip_tags($mystring);
> ```
>
> This is my car. This may be a funny content.

you can also exclude some of the tags you wanna keep, for example:

> ```
> echo strip_tags($mystring,"<strike>");
> ```
>
> This is my car. This may be a <strike>funny</strike> content.

In your situation probably this last option will be useful if you want to keep some tags and replacing them manually (for example br with \n ...)